# android: how to setup background color of listfragment without any view

Tags: android, background, android-listfragment

I m using a list fragment with adapter, the data in which get loaded after a network call. When the data has not been loaded a progressbar appears by default. Which is great but during this time since list fragment did not return any view on onCreateView() the background remains the same of the activity which started this list fragment. How can I set the background color of this list fragment. I tried doing so in the onViewCreated()

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ListView l = getListView();
    l.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.online_coupon_background_color));
}
```

But its still showing up transparent background color which just puts the progressbar on the activity that started it.

[image]

Comment: Hey, could you tell me the color code for both the blue and the green in the picture above? (With alpha if set manually). Thank you!

Comment: android:background="#D00098cb"
,         android:background="#D027b373"

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found where to change the color. It has to be changed in the parent on listfragment. In my case it was PagerSlidingTabStrip's xml layout file.